# Difference between TCL 'sleep' and 'after' command

Tags: tcl, expect

I am working on expect scripting. I want to understand the difference between sleep and after. Any example will help me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

There are three different entities:

## The Tclx's sleep

The `sleep` command from the `Tclx` package. According to the documentation, it takes a decimal argument, taken to be the number of seconds to sleep. However, the fraction part is truncated. That means `sleep 2.5` will sleep for two seconds.

## The Expect's sleep

The `sleep` command from the `Expect` package. This is similar to its counterpart from the `Tclx` package. However, `sleep 2.5` means sleeping for 2.5 seconds, there is no truncation.

## After

Finally, the built-in `after`, which is a totally different beast. The `after` command takes its first input as the number of milliseconds to sleep off. This is the "synchronous" mode Jerry refers to. After also takes a second argument. In this case, after returns a token right away. After the specified time, the script will be executed. With the token, you can cancel the script.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`sleep` is similar to `after` "synchronous" mode, with the difference being that (emphasis mine):

> Tcl's built-in [`after`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/808) command uses delay units of **milliseconds** whereas the TclX/Expect command works with **seconds** (i.e., a factor of 1000 different). Be careful when converting.<sup>[[1]](http://wiki.tcl.tk/933)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

My try at a short explanation:

The Tcl sleep will like the TclX sleep just pause the script.

The after command can pause the script, but it is normally used for *event based programming*. It can execute a script after the elapsed time (if the *event loop* is running).

More on this [see here at beedub.com](http://www.beedub.com/book/2nd/event.doc.html).